# Site Workflow add item in list automatically after 1 hour pause

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

- Workflow should use only one column “Title” from the list.
- Workflow should run in such a way that it should create an item every hour .
- Steps should be first create item then pause for 1 hour then a loop that should take you to start of workflow.

Comment: Yes, all doable using a SPD 2013 workflow with a loop, a Wait action and a REST and an Add Item action. What have you tried so far and what errors/issues are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

For better testing, I set to create an item every minute.

For your Transition to stage, have it redirect back up to the first stage.

[image]

[image]

In addition, only SharePoint 2013 workflow has the Transition to stage option.

You need to create SharePoint workflow 2013.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to create a workflow that keeps looping over and over and over. Eventually it will fail and you might not know it before it's too late.

The best way would be to use a scheduler to kick off the workflow every hour, but SharePoint does not come with any scheduler. You could use powershell for it though - assuming you have a server to run it off.

If we're talking out of the box solutions I would use 2010 workflows for it the following way.

Create a 2010 workflow that runs on create item in the list of hourly items. The workflow should pause for 1 hour, then create a new item and complete. Since you're using 2010 workflows the new items it created will kick off the workflow on the new item (2013 does not behave like this), whoch in turn will wait 60 minutes and create another item. This will happen over and over again.

The big difference here is that you instance new workflows every hour, not having the same workflow running over and over. It's not by any means failsafe, but it's the best we can do OOB.

Comment: Thank you, was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to try this solution with Microsoft Flow. You have there more powerful feature and you also have better debugging tools to monitor your workflow.